# How to wait to bind service if fragments created staticaly

Tags: android, service, bind, fragment

I have one anoying problem. I have a fragment staticaly defined in activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/tab_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.trilobitsol.one.TabFragmentNew" >
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

In activity's onCreate I bind to the service and in onServiceConnected I receive a service:

```
private ServiceConnection serviceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
            service = ((AlarmService.AlarmBinder)binder).getService();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            service = null;
        };
    };
```

However in onCreateView of the fragment I have code dependent on service got in the Activity and the problem is that onCreateView of the fragment is called before service is actually received. How to overcome this annoying problem?

Thanks in advance.
Jardo

**Solved:**
Thanks to @Karakuri advice, instead of creating tab fragments (where in onCreateView() is service dependent code) in TabFragmentNew.onCreateView() I have moved it to separate method which I call in onSeviceConnected(...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Whatever code in your fragment that depends on your Activity should be postponed at least to the `onActivityCreated()` callback of your fragment. You can store references to the Views you need to update when you inflate (or create) the View hierarchy in `onCreateView()`</strike>

**Edit:**
Try either of the following:

1. Make your fragment bind to the service instead. You can use `getActivity().bindService(...)`
2. Give your fragment a unique id or tag. When your activity gets the `onServiceConnected()` callback, have it find your fragment and call some public method on it

Fragment code:

```
public void serviceConnected(/*any args you want*/) {
    // ...
}
public void serviceDisonnected(/*any args you want*/) {
    // ...
}
```

Activity code:

```
private ServiceConnection serviceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
        service = ((AlarmService.AlarmBinder)binder).getService();
        TabFragmentNew fragment = (TabFragmentNew) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.tab_fragment);
        if (fragment != null) fragment.serviceConnected(...);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        service = null;
        TabFragmentNew fragment = (TabFragmentNew) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.tab_fragment);
        if (fragment != null) fragment.serviceDisconnected(...);
    };
};
```

Comment: Yes, I know but if the fragment is defined staticaly in layout, I do not control when it is inflated.

Comment: Accepted :) Maybe it helps some late hour developers